# Handle HTTP Basic Authorization header in Spring

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, http-headers, spring-3

I try to authenticate (Basic Auth) to my Spring application by sending the credentials in the HTTP header.

I have protected, e.g., the resource

```
http://localhost:8080/app/home
```

Non-authenticated users get redirected to

```
http://localhost:8080/app/login.jsp
```

Now I send a GET request to localhost:8080/app/home with the encoded credentials in the HTTP header like this:

```
Authorization: Basic c2VjcmV0dXNlcjpzZWNyZXRwd2Q=
```

I use the "Advanced Rest Client" Chrome plugin to send the request, so I'm quite sure the header is sent correctly. But the server answers with a redirect to the login.jsp page.

It seems Spring does not take the Authorization header. Do I need to configure my Spring application to accept the "Authorization: Basic" HTTP header?

This is my security-config.xml:

```
<http use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/login.jsp?authorization_error=true" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
         <intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp" access="permitAll" />
         <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

           <form-login authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?authentication_error=true" default-target-url="/home"
            login-page="/login.jsp" login-processing-url="/login.do" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/index.jsp" logout-url="/logout.do" /> 
        <anonymous />
</http>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a http-basic tag inside the http tag. Add realm name as well.

```
<http realm="My application name" ...>
  <http-basic />
  ...
</http>
```